# Drawing your own tab bar?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitabbar

I want to customize my tab bar user interface some thing like this .

[image: customized tab bar]
<sub>(source: [mactalk.com.au](http://www.mactalk.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Postage-1.png))</sub>

So can anyone tell me how to prepare these types of ui layout or rendering ?

Thanks ,

Answer (score 2):

To get this level of customisation, you're going to need to start from scratch and write your own control, there's no two ways about it.

Apple don't provide any way to customise the UI of a tab bar, and if you were to modify Apple's tab bar beyond the expected user experience it currently provides, you'd be in violation of the Human Interface Guidelines, which may cause Apple to take issue and reject your app.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer ,

But can you also redirect me how to start to write such kind of control on my own .

or is there any third party control which I can reuse .