# Resize width of Tab Bar iPhone

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I am a bit new to iPhone development, and I am not sure if this might even be possible, but I have an app with the Tab Bar at the bottom.  What I want to do is shrink the width of the bar.

In other words instead of the tab bar taking up the whole screen width I want it to take up the middle 70% (or so).  Is this possible in iPhone at all?

I can't seem to change it in the .xib file, but thought maybe I could change it dynamically somehow.  Really don't want to have to implement it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in iOS. (Character limit)

Comment: Do you know if there is any documentation on that lack of configurability?

Comment: @MikeIsrael Apple want it that way, it is not intended to be configurable.

Comment: Pjotr I recently learned about overriding the drawRect function for the navigation bar which I used to create a custom navigtation bar, could something similar be done for the tab bar?

Comment: I would guess your app gets rejected, but you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911975/iphone-how-can-i-build-my-own-tabbar & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948574/drawing-your-own-tab-bar

Comment: Thanks good to know.  I am an Android programmer and just used to being able to change almost anything the way I want it.  Now gotta worry about the man striking me down.

Comment: No problem:) You are restricted by many things, or atleast they can become potential problems with getting your app approved. I will also warn you about that a UITabBarController only can be used as a root controller. This means, you can only use it as the one you add on the window. I faced many problems doing this (found out to late) and had to redo a lot in my app. Good luck!